# Want to list all merged branches

Tags: git, github

I wanted to list all merged branches. Whether it merged into master or any other feature branch. Irrespective of any branch, if there was PR raised and it has merged then it should come to list.

Comment: I recommend looking at the documentation for the github api to see which endpoints will help answer your question. You should be able to get a list of all PRs using the api. Alternatively, look at the github cli documentation to see if it can do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`git branch --merged <Branch name that you want to see branches merged to> -a`

For example:
`git branch --merged master -a`.